# Question about homotopy equivalence

Tags: analysis, homotopy-theory, homology-cohomology, applications, deformation-theory

I have this proof but I don't understand why $i\circ j$ induces a homotopy equivalence, and how to see $j_*$ is injective at the level of homology?

$X$ is a Banach space

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The fact that $i\circ j: B_\infty X^-\hookrightarrow X\backslash X^+$ is a homotopy equivalence follows from the fact that both 
$$X^-\backslash \{0\}\hookrightarrow X\backslash X^+$$
and 
$$ B_\infty X^-\hookrightarrow X^-\backslash \{0\}$$
are homotopy equivalences. In fact the smaller spaces can be seen as deformation retracts of the larger ones.

**Edit:** Press $X\backslash X^{+}$ in the direction of $X^-$ to get the deformation retract of $X\backslash X^+$ to $X^-\backslash\{0\}$. That is $$x^++x^-\mapsto x^++tx^-.$$
Similarly for the other deformation retract, any $x\in X^-$ such that $|x|<R$ can be radially pushed towards the sphere radius $R$ in $X^-$ (which is the boundary of $B_\infty X^-$).

Comment: Please, I don't understand how we can see that "the smaller spaces can be seen as deformation retracts of the larger one" and is the composition of two homotopy equivalences is a homotopy equivalence? Thank you

Comment: Yes, composition of two homotopy equivalences is a homotopy equivalences. For the other statements, please see edit.

Comment: why precesly $X\setminus\{0\}$ please? is there an other methode please i don't understand this please, thank you

Comment: Can we see directly that $B_{\infty}X^-$ is a strong deformation retract of $X\setminus X^-$ ? thank you

Comment: Why $X^-\setminus B_{\infty}X^-\rightarrow X^-\setminus\{0\}$ please please

Comment: please why you don't answer me ? why you $X\setminus B_{\infty} X^-$ and not $B_{\infty}X^-$ directly ? please

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer more clearly. You can construct the deformation retract from $X\backslash X^+$ to $B_\infty X^-$ directly, but it will require some effort. For simplicity, try the simple cases first (each of the spaces $X^+$ and $X^-$ has dimension $1$ or $2$).

Comment: but you why the second deformation is from $X\setminus B_{\infty}X^-$ ?

Comment: Whene i compute the two i foud a homotopy equivalence from $X\setminus B_{\infty}X^- $ to $X\setminus X^+$ but I need a homotopy equivalence from $B_{\infty}X^- $ to $X\setminus X^+$

Comment: That was a mistake of the second homotopy equivalence. It should be just $B_\infty X^-$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: but why you take $|x|>R$ ? and please can we say that $i\circ j$ is bijectiv ?

Comment: $i\circ j$ is *not* bijective.

Comment: So we can't see directly that $i\circ j$ is an  homotopy equivalence ?